# "Unresolved Variable" caused by very long expression in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Because I'm receiving a highly nested object from my backend, I'm trying to use a very long expression:

```
<span>{{monitorValues.monitor.eventCounters[0].propertyCounters[0].total}}</span>
```

At calling the array `propertyCounters`, Webstorm shows me the hint "Unresolved Variable" and nothing will be shown. The farest expression that works is `monitorValues.monitor.eventCounters[0].propertyCounters`, which shows me the whole array then.
How can I make the full expression work to show the values that I want to show?

Comment: you can also create a function in scope or controller that returns that and call it instead, that should work OK

Comment: any reason you can't set another variable like `$scope.eventCounters` as subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just outsourced the expression into the js file like:

```
$scope.getValue = function(eventIndex, propIndex, index){

    var eventCounter = $scope.monitorValues.monitor.eventCounters[eventIndex];
    var propCounter = eventCounter.propertyCounters[propIndex];
    var valueCounter = propCounter.total[index];

    return valueCounter;
}
```

Now it works.